# Checking Value in MYSQL Before Registering Users

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a registration app in android studio(with PHP and MYSQL). In my database I have two tables:

table1 (For saving firstName and lastname)

and

table2 (contains 100 activation codes).

In register activity I have 3 fields: `FirstName`, `LastName` and `activation code`.

Before the user data is inserted into table1, this is very important that activation code must be checked with data in table2. If this value exists in table2, then the data is inserted into table1(registration done) and after successful import, delete the same value(activation code) in table2. If data does not exist in table2, then data is not inserted and show a toast error.

I'm new at this, so bear with me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not how I would approach user registration.  I think you should first insert a new user record, assuming the username is not taken.  Then, send the user an activation link of some kind.  Only once the user has verified his email address should you allow login to proceed.

Comment: Yes, I know this.  I'm saying I disagree with your assessment of the problem.

Comment: hi Tim,i just want  password field checked  with queries in table2

Comment: before that I gave a code to  a user and I don't want that code to be used again.

Comment: What you are doing is also not wrong but you need to generate new activation codes everyday and send mail to new users by selecting any code randomly . Before sending mail update table1 against the user for which you are sending mail with the code selected for that user . When the link is clicked catch the code from the URL and the username which also can be put in the mail link encrypted . Now match both and if success then change the user status to 1 .

Answer (score 0):

This solution is in php

```
$res = mysqli_query('SELECT * from activation_table WHERE your_code = "'.$activation_code.'"');
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){
  mysqli_query('INSERT INTO user(firstName, lastName) VALUES("'.$fname.'","'.$lname.'")');
  mysqli_query('DELETE FROM activation_code WHERE your_code = "'.$activation_code.'"');
}else{
  // your error message
}
```

I hope this solves your problem!

Comment: A solution should be better than this. 1: it should use transaction because you have multiple CRUD queries; 2: your answer didn't use prepare statement so that it could be vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: I did not emphsize on these because i thought this was for acedemic purposes. Yet thanks for the advice

Comment: Thanks For Every Thing And Every Ones.